# How to shutdown CompletionService after completing currently executed tasks

Tags: java, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I have something like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
CompletionService<Boolean> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
int i = 0;
while (i < 40) {
  completionService.submit(getTask());
  i++;
}
executor.shutdown();
System.out.println("SHUTDOWN");
```

After calling `shutdown` all submitted tasks are executed. If I call `shutdownNow`, then currently executed threads are throws `java.lang.InterruptedException`.

Is there are any way to wait currently executed tasks to complete and don't execute other submitted tasks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) allows the currently submitted tasks to complete, but rejects new ones:

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.

If you want to wait in your `main` thread for the executor to shut down, you can invoke [`executor.awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-):

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

If you want to allow the tasks that are currently *running* to complete, but discard the ones that are already submitted to the queue, you have a few choices:

- cancelling the Futures with [`cancel(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-):

  > Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if the task has already completed, has already been cancelled, or could not be cancelled for some other reason. If successful, and this task has not started when cancel is called, this task should never run.
  >
  > **Returns**:
  >   false if the task could not be cancelled, typically because it has already completed normally; true otherwise
- wrapping your `Runnable`/`Callable` with a custom `CancellableRunnable/Callable` (depending on what your `getTask()` returns):

  ```
  class CancellableRunnable implements Runnable {

      private final AtomicBoolean shouldRun;
      private final Runnable delegate;

      public CancellableRunnable(AtomicBoolean shouldRun, Runnable delegate) {
          this.shouldRun = shouldRun;
          this.delegate = delegate;
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
          if (shouldRun.get()) {
              delegate.run();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  and the usage in your example:

  ```
  AtomicBoolean shouldRun = new AtomicBoolean(true);
  while (i < 40) {
    completionService.submit(new CancellableRunnable(shouldRun, getTask()));
    i++;
  }
  shouldRun.set(false);
  executor.shutdown();
  ```

Comment: I don't need all submitted tasks to complete. I need to wait only currently executed 2 tasks and don't execute other submitted tasks.

Comment: It looks like what I need. Thank you, I'll try it

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after you have called `shutdown()`, the executor will accept no new tasks. Next you call `awaitTermination()` to await running tasks completing.

Comment: It doesn't work. When I do     `executor.shutdownNow();
    executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` then all submitted tasks will execute. I need to wait only currently executed 2 tasks and no others.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the first two results and then discard the other tasks, you can wait for the first two tasks to be completed then cancel the others, for example by calling shutdownNow if you don't need the completion service any longer.

```
Future<Boolean> result1 = copmletionService.take();
Future<Boolean> result2 = copmletionService.take();
completionService.shutdownNow();
```

Comment: This will not work. When I'll take two results some other tasks will start executing and there are still will be interrupted exception